# datanode is showing dead, how to bring it alive

Tags: hadoop

I have added 2 datanodes into,mapred.include,slaves files.

checked hadoop dfsadmin -report command, found below status.

Datanodes available: 0 (2 total, 2 dead)

How to bring them alive ? Please help me out.

Comment: Check the logs.What is the error,warnings etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps:

- Goto $HADOOP_HOME/bin
- ./hadoop-daemon.sh --config $HADOOP_HOME/conf start datanode